# Jenkins can not resolve dependencies?

Tags: android, mobile, jenkins

I'm very new to Jenkins. When Jenkins is trying to build my project I get a error saying "Can not resolve dependencies". Does anyone know a fix/ work around? Here is the error I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':mobile:_ukDebugCompile'.
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/20.0.0/appcompat-v7-20.0.0.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/20.0.0/appcompat-v7-20.0.0.jar
 Required by:
     project_name:mobile:unspecified

> Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+.
Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wearable/maven-metadata.xml
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wearable/ Required by:
     project_name:mobile:unspecified

* Try:Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I should mention there is no error in the project. It compiles, runs fine when I do it locally.

Comment: Have you updated the SDK on your jenkins machine?

Comment: Yes, it's downloaded on the machine that runs jenkins

Comment: I mean updated. Because it seems it can't find the libs. Please be sure you updated the SDK that your Jenkins configuration is targeting

Comment: Hi Pedro. I found a work around. Please see my answer below. The SDK is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around!

If anyone is in the same position, try this:
create a secondary git branch and make jenkins point the new branch. 
By doing this, the error didn't happen anymore.